# Erro The type or namespace name 'Model' could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Estou recebendo a mensagem de erro abaixo na instrução `@model FuncionarioModel`

> Erro: The type or namespace name 'FuncionarioModel' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
@model FuncionarioModel

<form asp-controller="Funcionarios" asp-action="Registro">
</form>
```

[image]

Comment: Lembre-se de sempre informar se está usando ASP.NET MVC (clássico, .NET Framework) ou ASP.NET Core. Além disso, por favor, poste o código e mensagens de erro em texto ao invés de imagens, isso permite que sua pergunta seja facilmente encontrada pela mensagem de erro e permite que pessoas com bloqueios de domínios externos possam tentar te ajudar _=)_

Answer (score 2):

Isso é porque provavelmente o `FuncionarioModel` está num *namespace* diferente - inferi isso porque é normal organizarmos os *namespaces* em pastas em projetos .NET.

Neste caso, ou você importa o *namespace* de forma "global", usando o arquivo `_ViewImports.cshtml` - [Veja mais na documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/layout?view=aspnetcore-3.1#importing-shared-directives):

```
@using Projeto.Models
```

Ou usa o nome completo da classe em `@model`.

```
@model Models.FuncionarioModel
```